# MongoDb C# find with regex?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm cutting my teeth on mongodb and I'm not sure how to covert this working query from 3T into code the C# MongoDb Driver will understand.

```
db.Orders.find({ accountNumber:"C7030529", searchTerms :{$regex: "300000309"}})
```

I can run this to find documents with the given accountNumber, but struggeling to figure out how I incorporate the regex function into the find...

```
var results = dbCollection.Find(x => x.AccountNumber == accountNumber)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I'm dumb and was over thinking it this works:

```
public ICollection<OrderDocumentModel> SearchOrders(string accountNumber, TimeFrame timeFrame, string search)
{
    var db = _mongoClient.GetDatabase("my-database");
    var regex = new Regex(search ?? string.Empty);

    var dbCollection = db.GetCollection<OrderDocumentModel>("my-collection");
    var results = dbCollection.Find(x => x.AccountNumber == accountNumber
                     && x.ReceivedDateTime >= timeFrame.FromDateTime
                     && x.ReceivedDateTime <= timeFrame.ToDateTime
                     && x.SearchTerms.Any(s => regex.IsMatch(s))
                     ).ToList();

    return results.ToList();
}
```